# What is the purpose of the compiler flag -DPURIFY?

Tags: openssl, compiler-flags

I came across a makefile building open SSL source and I was wondering what actions were performed by defining the PURIFY flag?
I googled around but only found a reference citing it's use, not an explanation about what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the compiler flag -DPURIFY?

It helps suppress spurious noise generated when purify analyzes the source code. For example, Purify will complain about the use of uninitialized variables when the variable is intended to be uninitialized, like when the PRNG is seeded with junk on the stack or heap. Most of the time, this is a programmer error. But in this particular case, its by design.

Clean compiles at elevated warnings is an art like no other. I make a clean compile a security gate when using `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`. That can be quite painful for a project that was not set up that way. I also require cleanliness under other tools, like Clang/GCC and its Sanitizers (`-fsanitze=undefined` and `-fsanitize=address`), and Valgind.

Clean analysis under Purify was the cause of the [Debian Random Number bug](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html) a few years back. The Debian folks were trying to silence a finding. (A few things went wrong in the Debian PRNG bug. It was an exercise in why airplanes crash).

Comment: Thanks, I was not even aware that Purify was a software package. I'm wondering now if we even use it or if the flag even needs to be there.

Comment: @yamex5 - yeah, its not as popular a others, like Clang ot GCC's Sanitizers. That's because of the cost. But its a very good tool. I also added info on the Debian PRNG bug.